# Define an infix operator that calls a custom function in Swift

Tags: swift, scope, operator-keyword, infix-notation

I am making an infix operator that calls a function, which is defined later in my program. Is it possible for this to work?

I would like something like

```
infix operator ∆+ { associativity left precedence 140 }

func ∆+ (left: String, right: String) -> String {
    return newAddition(left,second:right)
}
```

The problem I'm finding is that it can't pull from my later-defined code. I'm declaring both parts of this outside of the class statement.

Comment: Try creating making the corresponding assignment operator like: `func ∆+ (inout left: String, right: String) -> String` and check?

Comment: `The problem I'm finding is that it can't pull from my later-defined code.` What's the error?

Comment: Still what you meant by later-deinfed code?

Comment: I define this operator outside of the class body, but it's using 'newAddition()' which I have defined within the class body. It doesn't seem to be able to see it due to scope. "Use of unresolved identifier 'newAddition'"

Comment: And just for kicks, I moved all my other functions outside of the class, and now the ∆+ can see the scope of the functions it uses. And inside the class, I can call ∆+ correctly. Thank you guys!

Comment: @StevenJacks And this is not the answer you expected? If you have another answer, please post it. Otherwise accept this is an answer.

Comment: @StevenJacks I'm confused by the structuring of your code – the code you've shown is an operator that operates on Strings, so what business does it have calling functions from other classes? I'm also not convinced that adding a bunch more global functions is going to be a particularly nice solution to your problem, as it just pollutes the global namespace. Could you please explain the background of your problem a bit more? I suspect whatever logic you've put in `newAddition` should be in the operator function itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Custom operator functions defined in global scope, also you can define global functions.

```
import UIKit

infix operator ∆+ { associativity left precedence 140 }

func ∆+ (left: String, right: String) -> String {
    return newAddition(left,second:right)
}

func newAddition(left: String, second: String) -> String
{
    return left + second
}

//....... Other sutffs
```